# Casting HashMap Key Iterator to AbstractIterator

Tags: java, collections, guava, classcastexception

I have following code:

```
class SomeIterator<T> extends AbstractIterator<T> { ... }
```

`AbstractIterator` it's the guava class that provides a skeletal implementation of the {@code Iterator} interface. So it extends `UnmodifiableIterator<E>` which implements `Iterator<E>`

But when I try to cast something like this:

```
Set<Object> hashSet = new HashSet<Object>();
SomeIterator iterator = (SomeIterator) hashSet.iterator();
```

I got an exception:

```
ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator cannot be cast to com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator
```

What is the problem with my code?

Thanks for your hep!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HashSet`'s iterator is actually of type:

```
HashMap$KeyIterator
```

which extends

```
HashMap$HashIterator
```

which implements

```
Iterator
```

As you can see, the guava `AbstractIterator` is clearly not in that inheritance chain. Thus you can't cast to it.

Answer (score 0):

HashSet has his own Iterator. try this:

```
Set<Object> hashSet = new HashSet<Object>();
Iterator<Obejct> iterator = hashSet.iterator();
```

From HashSet:

```
HashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean dummy) {
    map = new LinkedHashMap<>(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
}

public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return map.keySet().iterator();
}
...
```

From LinkedHashMap:

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
    Set<K> ks = keySet;
    return (ks != null ? ks : (keySet = new KeySet()));
}

private final class KeySet extends AbstractSet<K> {
    public Iterator<K> iterator() {
        return newKeyIterator(); //^ -> KeyIterator extends HashIterator<K>
    }
    ...
}
```